# Is it possible to apply the El Gamal encryption/decryption technique using Edwards curve in Montgomery form

Tags: elliptic-curves, elgamal-encryption, ed25519, montgomery-multiplication

I've been trying to understand the ElGamal encryption/decryption technique. I plan to use it for sending a private message to the server. That is: Alice needs to send $Pm$ (private message encoded via Koblitz's or some other mapping on an elliptic curve) across to Bob.

Alice knows Bob's Public key $(P_{Bob})$, Only Alice has her private key $k$. $G$ is the generator of the curve that both Alive and Bob have agreed on (including other curve domain parameters).

So assuming the above the private message is converted to two cipher points $$\left([k]G, (P_m + [k]P_{bob})\right)$$ and sent to Bob, Bob extracts $Pm$ as follows

1. Bob multiplies his private key $b$ with the first point $[k]G$ to get the shared secret $[b\cdot k]G$
2. Bob subtracts the above from the second cipher point
   $$(P_m + [k]P_{bob}) - [b]([k]G) = P_m + [kb]G - [bk]G = P_m$$
3. Bob gets the private point $P_m$ and decodes the message from $P_m$ using Koblitz's or some other mapping.

**Note:** Please find this [video](https://youtu.be/keL8Gb38pVw?t=1864) which explains the above.

I assume the curve has to be represented in Weierstrass form for the Point addition i.e $P_m + [kb]P$.

1. But the question is can I do it on Edwards curve in Edward's represented form? i.e $ed25519B$.
2. Also can I do the same on $curve25519$ i.e Montgomery form.

The reason for using the Edward curve is because of speed/efficiency optimization since I plan to  use this on a microcontroller (nrf5340 w/ CRYPTOCELL-312)

I am referring to [elliptic npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elliptic) pkg for the PoC on Javascript, I am currently testing this PoC
in JS.

I understand that curve25519 in Montgomery form doesn't support unified add but supports differential point addition and makes use of ladder point addition and doubling for multiplication. Am just not sure how to go about the point addition technique assuming I strictly need to keep the point addition/multiplication cost as low as possible.I.e use ed25519 and/or curve25519(x25519)

I also understand there are ways to convert points from one form to another, If this is the crux to a solution to my question  I would also like to know its feasibility in terms of popular libraries in JS/node and C/C++ like libsodium or something.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. I've edited your question with $\LaTeX$/MathJax, could you check for some possible mistakes? What is the size of your messages? Why are you not using Diffie-Hellman and AES-CCM or ChaCha20 for encryption? There is a way to extract $y$ coordinate of after the Montgomery ladder, however, I've no information about the cost. AFAIK it was CHES 2003 paper.

Comment: I size of my message is just one point Pm, for now I just want to encode one ASCII character to the point Pm on the curve.  I dont want to use DH because I dont want to generate a shared secret.

Comment: The size of my message is just one point Pm, for now I just want to encode one ASCII character to the point Pm on the curve.  I dont want to use DH because I dont want to generate a shared secret. Infact the thing am trying to do i implement a nounce for a handshake over BLE, a part of that nounce is (kG,  Pm + kPb), this is sent by the client, the server then needs to extract Pm from it to confirm that is a valid client. The above is a cipher point pair, i dont need the y coordinate of kG and neither the y coordinate of (Pm + kPb).